# vba marker size

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write some VBA code to individually change the sizes of markers in an Excel graph.  I can change line weight, marker colour and so on, but not weight. I have serched on line and keep finding MarkerSize as the parameter but when I use it I get a 438 error and the message "Object doesn't support this property or method."
I am working in Excel 2007 and have seen comments that it does not do everything it should, so maybe this is not possible.  Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks!
My code is:

```
Sub Size()

Dim i As Double, plotcounter As Double

plotcounter = 1 ' The number of the series to plot '
   For i = 1 To 30 ' rows in sheet
Charts(1).SeriesCollection(plotcounter).Points(i).Format.MarkerSize = Cells(i, 5)

   Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try leaving off the `.Format` part of your statement. It appears from the [language reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174283%28v=office.11%29.aspx) that `MarkerSize` is a property of the `Point` object.

But Microsoft does have this annoying tendency to change things from one version of Excel to the next, and of not always following their own standards (and don't get me started on the differences in VBA between Mac and PC!)...

Comment: That works, thank you Floris! I'd looked it up in the 2007 language reference and it only refers to MarkerSize as a series object there, which made me wonder if changing individual points was even possible. Clearly it is. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad this works for you. You might consider "accepting" my answer by clicking the little check mark...